# SQL Server : String manipulation to write out SEO friendly titles

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I need to write the Titles of songs in a SEO frienly format, following a few rules given to me.

The maximum lentgh is 52 characters. Currently the truncation occurs for records that begin with a CL, and that pertain to a group of association ids.

The additional rules I have to apply are:

- If the seo_friendly_title ends with a '-' remove it.
- If the
  truncation ends in the middle of a word, or a space, then move to the
  next space (end of next word).

I think I have to add nested `CASE` statement(s) to accomplish this, but I don't know where to add this new checks.

I would like to ask for your help in completing this algorithm, hopefully someone can share their experience and show/ explain how to do this.

Many thanks.

Here is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT
    [sfwt].[seo_friendly_title]
,   CASE    
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) THEN 
            LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52)
    END [seo_final_title]
FROM
    [dbo].[SEOFriendly_WorkingTable] [sfwt]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] [pd]
    ON [pd].[ProductID] = [sfwt].[pf_id]
WHERE [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%'
ORDER BY    
    [sfwt].[pf_id];
```

And the output:

```
seo_friendly_title  seo_final_title
prelude-no-5-for-trumpet-and-piano-johann-sebastian-bach    prelude-no-5-for-trumpet-and-piano-johann-sebastian-
prelude-no-8-for-trumpet-and-piano-johann-sebastian-bach    prelude-no-8-for-trumpet-and-piano-johann-sebastian-
highlights-from-the-lord-of-the-rings-the-return-of-the-king    highlights-from-the-lord-of-the-rings-the-return-of-
air-ecossais-spirituoso-e-marciale-opus-107-no-10-f-instrument-piano    air-ecossais-spirituoso-e-marciale-opus-107-no-10-f-
air-ecossais-spirituoso-e-marciale-opus-107-no-10-c-instrument-piano    air-ecossais-spirituoso-e-marciale-opus-107-no-10-c-
air-de-la-petite-russie-opus-107-no-3-bb-instrument-piano   air-de-la-petite-russie-opus-107-no-3-bb-instrument-
air-de-la-petite-russie-opus-107-no-3-eb-instrument-piano   air-de-la-petite-russie-opus-107-no-3-eb-instrument-
shell-be-coming-round-the-mountain-c-instrument-and-piano   shell-be-coming-round-the-mountain-c-instrument-and-
shell-be-coming-round-the-mountain-f-instrument-and-piano   shell-be-coming-round-the-mountain-f-instrument-and-
9-ecossaises-from-38-waltzer-landler-und-ecossaisen-op-18   9-ecossaises-from-38-waltzer-landler-und-ecossaisen-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Updated 09/27

```
  SELECT
    [sfwt].[seo_friendly_title]
,   CASE    
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) and LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52) LIKE '%-' THEN LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 51)
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) THEN LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52)
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) and LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52) NOT like '%-' 
            and left(Replace([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),''),1) <> '-'
            and Charindex('-',Replace([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),'') = 0 then [sfwt].[seo_friendly_title]
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) and LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52) NOT like '%-' 
            and left(Replace([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),''),1) <> '-'
            and Charindex('-',Replace([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),'') != 0 then LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 51 + Charindex('-',Replace([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),'')))
    END [seo_final_title]
FROM
    [dbo].[SEOFriendly_WorkingTable] [sfwt]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] [pd]
    ON [pd].[ProductID] = [sfwt].[pf_id]
WHERE [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%'
ORDER BY    
    [sfwt].[pf_id];
```

Comment: I am going to use this as a starting point and as I make progress I will possibly open a new question. Thank you Rahul.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for point 1 but I am not clear for point number two which is "If the truncation ends in the middle of a word, or a space, then move to the next space (end of next word)." can you share the example?

```
SELECT
    [sfwt].[seo_friendly_title]
,   CASE    
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) and LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52) LIKE '%-' THEN LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 51)
        WHEN [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%' AND [pd].[AssociationID] IN ( 1, 3, 4 ) THEN LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52)
    END [seo_final_title]
FROM
    [dbo].[SEOFriendly_WorkingTable] [sfwt]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProductData] [pd]
    ON [pd].[ProductID] = [sfwt].[pf_id]
WHERE [sfwt].[pf_id] LIKE 'CL%'
ORDER BY    
    [sfwt].[pf_id];
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, here is an example string. Original: air-ecossais-allegretto-op-107-no-9-f-instrument-piano. After truncation: air-ecossais-allegretto-op-107-no-9-f-instrument-pia. In this case, I would have to make an exception and go to the end of the word: piano.

Comment: Try this one out. posting in another answer

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am not sure I follow your latest query all the way, but I am trying to run it to see what results it gives. Whilst doing that, this line: THEN LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 51) + CHARINDEX('-', REPLACE([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title],LEFT([sfwt].[seo_friendly_title], 52),'')) is throwing an error:: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a-rumor-in-st-petersburg' to data type int."